# How can I force lstlisting to expand an argument?

Tags: macros, listings, expansion, key-value

I'm trying to use the `listings` package with a variable language (it's actually for a package). However, I can't seem to pass a macro as the value half of a key-value pair. Here's a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\lang{Java}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

% writes "Java" to document
\lang

% writes with no formatting (as expected)
\begin{lstlisting}
int x = 2; // declare, initialize variable
\end{lstlisting}

% writes with Java formatting (as expected)
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java] % same effect with language={Java}
int x = 2; // declare, initialize variable
\end{lstlisting}

% fails with Error: language Java undefined
\begin{lstlisting}[language=\lang]
int x = 2; // declare, initialize variable
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

In reality, this is part of a package that itself includes a key-value system, so optimally you should be able to do `\usepackage[language=Java]{foo}` and it will later be able to `\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]` properly.

I also tried using `\edef` instead of `\def`, and using `\expandafter` (though that seems backwards to me). What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You hve to expand the parameter. A visually better solution which is based on `\edef` (the same as Heiko's answer):

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\lang{Java}
\usepackage{listings}
\def\expandparam\begin#1[#2]{\edef\tmp{\noexpand\begin{#1}[#2]}\tmp}
\begin{document}

% writes "Java" to document
\lang

% writes with no formatting (as expected)
\begin{lstlisting}
int x = 2; // declare, initialize variable
\end{lstlisting}

% writes with Java formatting (as expected)
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java] % same effect with language={Java}
int x = 2; // declare, initialize variable
\end{lstlisting}

% The \expandaparams is used here:
\expandparam
\begin{lstlisting}[language=\lang]
int x = 2; // declare, initialize variable
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\def\expandparam\begin#1[#2]{\edef\tmp{\noexpand\begin{#1}[#2]}\tmp}`, together with `\expandparam` before `\begin`, made my day, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The first part of `\begin{lstlisting}[...` can be put into `\edef` to expand the macros. The expansion of `\begin` is prevented by `\noexpand`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\lang{Java}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\edef\next{%
  \noexpand\begin{lstlisting}[language=\lang
}\next]
int x = 2; // declare, initialize variable
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]